# Convert list of dictionaries into dict

Tags: python, dictionary

I have the following list of one-element dictionaries:

```
[{'\xe7': '\xe7\x95\xb6\xe6\x96\xb0\x.'}, {'...\xe6\x991\xe7\xa8\x': 'asdf'}]
```

How would I convert this into a dict? To get:

```
{
    '\xe7': '\xe7\x95\xb6\xe6\x96\xb0\x.',
    '...\xe6\x991\xe7\xa8\x': 'asdf'
}
```

Comment: What do you want to the final dict to look like?

Comment: Related: [How do I merge two dictionaries in a single expression in Python?](/q/38987/4518341)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can do it with a *dict comprehension*:

```
{k:v for element in dictList for k,v in element.items()}
```

This syntax only works for Python  versions >= 2.7 though. If you are using Python < 2.7, you'd have to do something like:

```
dict([(k,v) for element in dictList for k,v in element.items()])
```

If you're unfamiliar with such nesting inside a comprehension, what I've done is equivalent to:

```
newDict = {}
for element in dictList:
    for k,v in element.items():
        newDict[k] = v
```

Comment: @mgilson Thanks for the correction... I'm still using 2.6 myself and I often hear about new upgrades meant for the 3x series only. Good to know I can almost use it ;).

Answer (score 1):

I'd probably just do:

```
dct = {}
for sub_dict in lst:
    dct.update(sub_dict)
```

Comment: Is there a way to do that with a list comprehension?

Comment: @David -- Probably, but I doubt it would be all that pretty... Any reason you want a comprehension?