# Merging list of dicts in python

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, maps, key

I have the dict in python in the following format:

```
dict1 = [{'Name':'a', 'value':20},{'Name':'b', 'value':10},{'Name':'c', 'value':15}]
```

I want output something like this:

```
dict2 = {'a':20, 'b':10, 'c':15 }
```

How to do it ?

Comment: what do you mean how to do it "more" efficiently, you havent shown your code, so we have no way to know or measure how efficient your current code is to be able to suggest to you how you could be more efficient.

Comment: Also dict1 is actually a list of dicts.....

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert list of dictionaries into dict](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28243504/convert-list-of-dictionaries-into-dict)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can do it with for loop efficiently.
Check this:

```
dict1 = [{'Name':'a', 'value':20},{'Name':'b', 'value':10},{'Name':'c', 'value':15}]
dict2 = dict()
for a in range(len(dict1)):
    dict2[dict1[a].get('Name')] = dict1[a].get('value')
print(dict2)
```

Output:

```
{'a': 20, 'b': 10, 'c': 15}
```

This is the easy way:

```
dict1 = [{'Name':'a', 'value':20},{'Name':'b', 'value':10},{'Name':'c', 'value':15}]
dict2={dc['Name']:dc['value'] for dc in dict1}
```