# TypeError: '_io.TextIOWrapper' object is not subscriptable when reading JSON

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

Here is an example of my json file and my code snippet causing errors. I'm trying to search the json file using the postid to retrieve the post title.

Thanks!

```
[
    {
        "gy36v6": "A good boy at a Minneapolis protest today"
    },
    {
        "gy7hpi": "Einstein lecturing at an HBCU"
    },
    {
        "gyddyc": "Soldier ant \ud83d\udc1c"
    },
    {
        "gyec4a": "It\u2019s not what I usually post but thought it was a cool cake I got."
    }
]
```

```
def post(postid):
 title = ''
 media = api.media_upload(postid)
 with open('used.json', 'r') as fileobj:
  title = fileobj[postid]   #<~~~ Line 17
```

The error is:

```
  File "c:\Users\mattm\Desktop\twitterbot\twitterpost.py", line 17, in post
    print(fileobj[postid])
TypeError: '_io.TextIOWrapper' object is not subscriptable
```

Comment: Well, yeah. You didn't use the `json` library to deserialize the input. You can't just open a file and assume you can treat its contents as a dictionary

Answer (score 2):

`fileobj` is just a file object; it doesn't know that it contains JSON. Use the [`json` library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#module-json) to convert it to Python data, for example:

```
import json

def post(postid):
    with open('used.json', 'r') as fileobj:
         data = json.load(fileobj)
    title = data[postid]
    return title

print(post(0))  # -> {'gy36v6': 'A good boy at a Minneapolis protest today'}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Unfortunately this immediately led to an error with 'title = data[postid]' saying 'TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str'. Any clarification you can give would be super helpful.

Comment: @Matt Your JSON is a list of dicts. You probably want to [convert it to a flat dict](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28243504/4518341).