# How to remove square brackets from 2D Python array for setting to Firebase RTDB

Tags: python, firebase, list, firebase-realtime-database, multidimensional-array

I have a basic web scrapper getting weather data to post to Firebase. At the moment all my data is stored in a 2D list for ease of processing, however the Python list includes square brackets for formatting (obviously).
My problem is that Firebase RTDB sees each square bracket as a new item in the Json tree, so say this is my list when printed to the terminal:

```
[{'Weather Data': [{'Houston': {'weather': 'Chance of showers', 'uvindex': '0', 'category': 'Low', 'timeabove': 'None'}}, {'Seattle': {'weather': 'Chance of showers', 'uvindex': '3', 'category': 'Moderate', 'timeabove': '1 pm to  2 pm'}}]}]
```

I want my Json tree to look like:

```
Weather Data
    Houston
       weather: Chance of showers
       uvindex: 0
       category: Low
       timeabove: None
etc...
```

However, this is what comes up on my RTDB:

```
0
   Weather Data
       0
         Houston
            weather: Chance of showers
            uvindex: 0
            category: Low
            timeabove: None

      1
        Seattle
            weather: Chance of showers
            uvindex: 0
            category: Low
            timeabove: None
etc etc
```

From playing around with the db I can see that it is the square brackets that are creating the extra nodes into the Json tree. Is there a way around the formatting in Firebase, or a function to clean up the list to convert it into a cleaner Json format? Json.dumps(x) creates the same problem. I'm hoping not to extract each individual list out of the 2D list if possiible.

Comment: I guess (because I don't know the full complexity of the structure) that this can be done with some Python code. Show your own effort (code) as properly formatted text in the question.

Comment: Is there only 1 `dict` in the outermost `list`? That is, is the `dict` with the `'Weather Data'` key the only `dict` in the outermost `list`?

Comment: @JonnyHenly Yes thats correct.

Comment: If my answer solves your problem, then I do believe this question is a duplicate of [Convert list of dictionaries into dict](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28243504/convert-list-of-dictionaries-into-dict). Though, your question also asks for a possible Firebase solution, in which case my answer is a duplicate but the question is not.

Answer (score 1):

In simple terms, just get rid of the `list`s, i.e. pull out the `dict`s in the wrapping `list`s:

```python
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import json

twoD = [{'Weather Data': [{'Houston': {'weather': 'Chance of showers', 'uvindex': '0', 'category': 'Low', 'timeabove': 'None'}}, {'Seattle': {'weather': 'Chance of showers', 'uvindex': '3', 'category': 'Moderate', 'timeabove': '1 pm to  2 pm'}}]}]

city_data = { city: data for val in twoD[0]['Weather Data'] for city, data in val.items()}

weather_data = {'Weather Data': city_data}

print(json.dumps(weather_data, indent=2))
```

Outputs:

```
{
  "Weather Data": {
    "Houston": {
      "weather": "Chance of showers",
      "uvindex": "0",
      "category": "Low",
      "timeabove": "None"
    },
    "Seattle": {
      "weather": "Chance of showers",
      "uvindex": "3",
      "category": "Moderate",
      "timeabove": "1 pm to  2 pm"
    }
  }
}
```